# Websocket on MAMP

Tags: javascript, ajax, websocket

I am working on a personal project that has a chat message system. I want the messages to update real time for both users when a new message is sent (like facebook chat). Although I have tried multiple ways to detect changes on the database and AJAX my PHP script that SELECTs the messages I can only update the sender's message in real time. The receiver can't see the new message unless they refresh their page. So I decided to use websockets on my local environment to keep the connection open and AJAX my messages.php script when there is a change on the database. However, when I create the websocket object:

```
var msgsSocket = new WebSocket("ws://www.localhost:8888/messages.php");
```

I am getting an error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.localhost:8888/messages.php' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

I also tested with the following URL strings:

```
www.localhost/messages.php
localhost:8888/messages.php
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is welcome.

P.S. I am using MAMP

Comment: It turns out i didn't have sockets installed on the server.

Comment: have you found any solution?